# Any good examples of Pig Accumulator Interface implementation that works?

Tags: performance, apache-pig, udf

I have a requirement to read millions of records from HDFS, enrich them and store them as an XML file in the batch of 10K records per XML file.

I have been experimenting with the Accumulator interface and set my pig.accumulative.batchsize to 2 for testing.

However, the method that gets invoked is the "exec()" instead of Accumulator's "accumulate" method.

Outline of my UDF class is as follows:

```
public class MyAccUDF extends EvalFunc <Tuple> implements Accumulator <Tuple>{

    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        //..
    }

    public void accumulate(Tuple b) throws IOException {
        //...
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        //..
    }

    public Tuple getValue() {
        //..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Accumulator interface is not guaranteed to be exercised every time. The book Programming Pig [outlines where the accumulator interface won't be honoured](http://books.google.ca/books?id=0zimI7NoObIC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=accumulator%20interface%20pig&source=bl&ots=O6U_T86OkE&sig=mzQr5OuejR-4jiTTWGGBCSQZJ2g):

> Whenever possible, Pig will choose to use the algebraic implementation of a UDF over
>   the accumulator. This is because the accumulator helps avoid spilling records to disk,
>   but it does not reduce network cost or help balance the reducers. If all UDFs in a
>   foreach implement Accumulator and at least one does not implement Algebraic, Pig will
>   use the accumulator. If at least one does not use the accumulator, Pig will not use the
>   accumulator. This is because Pig already has to read the entire bag into memory to pass
>   to the UDF that does not implement the accumulator, so there is no longer any value
>   in the accumulator.

Your UDF will have to implement its logic in both `exec()` and `accumulate()`. A simple example of this duplication of functionality can be found in [the `COUNT` UDF](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/COUNT.java).